# Mistake in page sizing

Tags: pdf, paper-size, size, resize

I have a very big problem. I've finished my latex project,I've been using a template that I found in Overleaf but I didn't notice that the page size is 17cmx22.5cm so when I print the file in a A4 sheet, it looks with very big margins . I've included some A3 pdf files in my project so I cannot just print the pdf file by clicking the option of adjusting to page size. 
My question is:
Is there any way to print the 17cmx22.5cm pages in A4 pages scaling up its content without adjust the A3 pages?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (i)  try to select template with correct/desired page size and compile your document with it. (ii) form more particular help we need to see your (small part of) document, which we can compile in out computers.

Comment: or print the A4 pages first, with scaling, then print the A3 pages without scaling, then put them together.